# Opencv streaming url python

Tags: python, opencv, stream

I want to process a streaming url with opencv and so, read it.
First I try to read and show video in window but i can't do it...
I tried several methods but none worked :

**1. File buffering**

This method consists of playing the video with another library, saving it to a file and read it live with opencv

Problem: Opencv can't open the file and raise a error

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fa6f3825a00] moov atom not found
OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "tmp.mp4"
```

**2. Open stream url with opencv**

This method consists in opening the url streaming directly with Opencv. It works but the video is not played at normal speed, it is read at the speed of data input, so if the video is low quality (less data) they load faster and is read faster. ..

In addition I get an error on opening:

```
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fe9f71e6920] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
```

**3. Decode bytes with Opencv**

This method consists in reading the data with an external library then decoding them with opencv. But Opencv can never decode the image.

This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import requests
import streamlink


class Cam:

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.stream = None
        self.stream_url = url

    def choose_stream(self):
        print("Loading stream...")
        streams = streamlink.streams(self.stream_url)
        stream = streams['360p']
        print("Loaded !")
        return stream

    def show_img(self, ret, img):
        try:
            if ret:
                cv2.imshow('result', img)
        except:
            print("DERP")

    def run_with_file_buffer(self):
        self.stream = self.choose_stream()
        buffer_file_name = "tmp.mp4"
        video_file = open(buffer_file_name, "wb")
        fd = self.stream.open()
        for i in range(0, 512):
            if (i % 256) == 0:
                print("Buffering {i}...".format(i=i), end="\r")
            new_bytes = fd.read(1024)
            video_file.write(new_bytes)
        print("Done buffering.")

        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(buffer_file_name)
        while True:
            new_bytes = fd.read(1024 * 16)
            video_file.write(new_bytes)
            ret, img = cam.read()
            self.show_img(ret, img)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
                break
        video_file.close()
        fd.close()

    def run_with_stream_url(self):
        self.stream = self.choose_stream()
        print("Reading : " + self.stream.url)
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(self.stream.url)
        if not cam.isOpened():
            print("Error opening video stream or file")
        while cam.isOpened():
            ret, img = cam.read()
            self.show_img(ret, img)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
                break

    def run_with_bytes(self):
        self.stream = self.choose_stream()
        fd = self.stream.open()
        data = b''
        while True:
            data += fd.read(1024)
            a = data.find(b'\xff\xd8')
            b = data.find(b'\xff\xd9')
            if a != -1 and b != -1:
                img_data = data[a:b + 2]
                data = data[b + 2:]
                np_data = np.frombuffer(img_data, dtype=np.uint8)
                # np_data = np.fromstring(img_data, dtype=np.uint8)
                if len(np_data) != 0: # Always false
                    img = cv2.imdecode(np_data, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    if img:
                        cv2.imshow('cam', img)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/{id}'
    cam = Cam(url)
    cam.run_with_bytes()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```